# Trying to bind a form model to a Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

this is my model i want to display lesCategories on a grid and Nom on an textBox:

```
public class StructureTypeViewModel
{

    public StructureTypeViewModel()
    {
        this.Nom = "";
        this.LesCategories = new List<CategorieTemplateViewModel>();
    }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int StructureID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Le nom de la structure")]
    public string  Nom { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Les catégories")]
    public List<CategorieTemplateViewModel> LesCategories { get; set; }
}
```

here my view :

```
    @using Kendo.Mvc.UI
    @model Parmenide.PoliceGenerator.Web.Template.Models.StructureTypeViewModel

    <style>
        .form-special {
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            max-width: 75%;
        }

    </style>


    <div class="form-special">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nom)
            @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.Nom)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new {placeholder = "Ex : Struture n°1", type = "text", @class = "k-textbox required"})
          )
</div>

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.LesCategories)
          .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.Nom);
              columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
          })
          .ToolBar(
              toolbar =>
              {
                  toolbar.Create().Text("Ajouter une catégorie");
              })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .Scrollable()
          .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height:250px;"})
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Batch(true)
              .ServerOperation(false)
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(p => p.CategorieID);
              })
              .PageSize(5)
          .Create(create => create.Action("EditingCustom_Create", "Home"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("EditingCustom_Update", "Home"))
          .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingCustom_Destroy", "Home"))
          )
          )
```

I have too problems on create update destroy action i don't understand the syntax to get the currents list of CategorieViewModel.

Comment: What is your implementation of EditingCustom_Create(), EditingCustom_Update(), and EditingCustom_Destroy()?  Take a look at the EditingController.cs implementation of this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing.